# Ошибка с markup == types.KeyboardsMarkup(resize_keyboard=True) при создании бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, cmd, telebot

Создаваю свеого первого бота в телеграмме через пайтон. Решил добавить inline keyboard, но код перестал работать и выдает ошибку: 
markup == types.KeyboardsMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
Не могу разобраться так как опыта мало. Помогите
Код:

```
import telebot
import config

from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):

#keyboard
    markup == types.KeyboardsMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Понедельник")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Вторник")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Среда")
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Четверг")
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Пятница")
    item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Суббота")
    item7 = types.KeyboardButton("Перемены")
    item8 = types.KeyboardButton("Сведение")
 
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Салам, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный ,чтобы был.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Понедельник':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Вторник':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Среда':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'ОРЭГ \nФизра \nСтатистика')
        if message.text == 'Четверг':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'Программирование \nБух.учёт \nИРиВС')
        if message.text == 'Пятница':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'Инструментальные средства \nКомпьютерная графика \nФизра')
        if message.text == 'Суббота':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Перемены':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'1 пара 8:00-9:20 \n2 пара 9:30-10:50 \n3 пара 11:00-12:20 \n4 пара 12:40-14:00')
        elif message.text == 'Сведение':
            
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Список", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Данные", callback_data='bad')
            
        markup.add(item1, item2)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'информация')
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'информация')
        

# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо просто заместо `markup == types.KeyboardsMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)` написать `markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)`

В итоге должно получиться так:

```
import telebot
import config

from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):

#keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True) # <--- тут ошибка, вы сравниваете, а не присваиваете переменной `markup` сам тип клавиатуры, также вы и тип клавиатуры неправильный написали
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Понедельник")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Вторник")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Среда")
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Четверг")
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Пятница")
    item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Суббота")
    item7 = types.KeyboardButton("Перемены")
    item8 = types.KeyboardButton("Сведение")
 
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Салам, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный ,чтобы был.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Понедельник':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Вторник':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Среда':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'ОРЭГ \nФизра \nСтатистика')
        if message.text == 'Четверг':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'Программирование \nБух.учёт \nИРиВС')
        if message.text == 'Пятница':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'Инструментальные средства \nКомпьютерная графика \nФизра')
        if message.text == 'Суббота':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Перемены':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'1 пара 8:00-9:20 \n2 пара 9:30-10:50 \n3 пара 11:00-12:20 \n4 пара 12:40-14:00')
        elif message.text == 'Сведение':
            
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Список", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Данные", callback_data='bad')
            
        markup.add(item1, item2)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'информация')
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'информация')
        

# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: markup=types.KeyboardsMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
AttributeError: module 'telebot.types' has no attribute 'KeyboardsMarkup' Выходит ошибка хотя сам телебот показывает что есть такой атрибут

Comment: Извините забыл исправить, обновил, теперь должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Понедельник")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Вторник")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Среда")
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Четверг")
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Пятница")
    item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Суббота")
    item7 = types.KeyboardButton("Перемены")
    item8 = types.KeyboardButton("Сведение")

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Hi, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот-дневник".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Понедельник':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Вторник':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Среда':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, u'ОРЭГ \nФизра \nСтатистика')
        if message.text == 'Четверг':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, u'Программирование \nБух.учёт \nИРиВС')
        if message.text == 'Пятница':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, u'Инструментальные средства \nКомпьютерная графика \nФизра')
        if message.text == 'Суббота':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Перемены':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                             u'1 пара 8:00-9:20 \n2 пара 9:30-10:50 \n3 пара 11:00-12:20 \n4 пара 12:40-14:00')
        elif message.text == 'Сведение':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Список", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Данные", callback_data='bad')
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Выход", callback_data='exit')
            markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "?", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'заполните список')
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'внесите данные')
            else:
                bot.edit_message_text("выход", call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=None)


    except:
        pass


# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]